# How to make variable globle in cypress which can we used in all TestCase in a spec file

Tags: cypress

I need to pass the Randomly generated string data in all my Test Cases but it is only working when i put this below code in all it() block
but i need to set this code somewhere i can access these values in all my it() block or in all my TestCases

FYI-beforeAll() and beforeEach() also not able to do this
so how can i make these thing global form where in can read in all my TestCases??

```
   `const Rs = new RandomString();
   var UserEmaill = Rs.getRandomUserEmail();
    cy.log(UserEmaill);
   var UserData = Rs.getRandomUser();
   cy.log(UserData)`
```

Comment: What is the error you get? It should work when you put this outside your `describe`

Comment: Yes it is working when i put this outside the describe but my req. is to use this randomly generated email accross all my it()/TestCases but when it switching one test to another it calling getRandomUserEmail() again but i want same emailid across all my test.
so how can i do this

Answer (score 1):

You can do in multiple ways. If you want to generate random strings in your tests, you can use `faker` npm module and you can do it easily... So you can do this in as many as tests possible....

```
npm install faker
let faker = require('faker');
cy.log(faker.internet.email());
```

But as you are saying that you want to use globally across multiple tests, So I suggest you to do below stuff in before hooks of `support/index.js`. and call those variable wherever you want.

Do as below in index.js and it will be done at before your tests execution..

```
let faker = require('faker');
before(() => {
  global.EMAIL1 = getRandomEmail();
  global.EMAIL2 = getRandomEmail();
  global.EMAIL3 = getRandomEmail();
  global.EMAIL4 = getRandomEmail();
  function getRandomEmail() {
    return faker.internet.email();
  }
})
```

In your test you can access as below

```
cy.log(global.EMAIL1);
```

It will work like charm, please use it and like the answer to reach to more people...

Comment: Hi am getting error(cant read form index,js) while doing this, can you pls explain that how should i configure this piece of code

Comment: Hi yes now it reading form index,js but there is two problems
1.Every time it is using different domin of mail ex- yahoo.com , gmail.com, hotmail.com....At every Run it is changing while i wrote my code function getRandomEmail() with domain name "mailinator.com"

2. Am using cy.log(global.EMAIL1); in two different It() blocks/TestCase coz i need same mail id in all my test case but here also after switching the test case it again calling getRandomEmail() function.
my req. is to use same mail id across all my tests is there any way that i can use one time generated mail id in all my tests

Comment: Am stuck in one thing only  that i need to use same data(Email) in all my test case in under one spec file which is randomly generated
is there anything that can i hold this value and use even after i switch one test case to another??

Answer (score -1):

Then it is super easy, all you have to do is generate the random email per test case. So that it would not be impacted by any other test and it will not impact others too. I still suggest you to use test data per test so that other test do not get effected... I think below snippet is enough for you.

```
let faker = require('faker');
describe('test suite', () => {
  it('test1', () => {
    var email1 = faker.internet.email().split('@')[0]+'@mailinator.com';
    cy.log(`test1 email is ${email1}`);
  });

  it('test2', () => {
    var email2 = faker.internet.email().split('@')[0]+'@mailinator.com';
    cy.log(`test2 email is ${email2}`);
  })
})
```

Comment: Hi Sir can u help me in this
cy.visit() failed because while attempting to visit a second unique domain/location/url in a single test case
I used cy.request() also but didn't work so how can we do this?? But i have to navigate two urls in single test, and can not divide test case. This is my TestCase

Comment: I posted this question stackoverflow also
pls help me out in this also

Comment: Cypress doesn't support multiple domain in the same test, they do not have such feature. Kindly take a look at https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3985